# How is the sequence generated via gradient descent uniformly bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Consider a function $f\in\mathcal{C}^2$ with Lipschitz continuous gradient (with constant $L$)- we also assume the function is lowerbounded and has at least one minimum. Let $\{x^k\}_k$ be the sequence generated by Gradient Descent algorithm with initial point $x^0$ and step-size $0<\alpha<2/L$:
\begin{equation}
x^{k+1}=x^k-\alpha\nabla f (x^k).
\end{equation} 
We know that the sequence will converge to a critical point.

Now consider the new function $\tilde{f}(x)=f(x)+x'Ax$ with some $A\succeq\mathbf{0}$. Let  $\{\tilde{x}^k\}_k$ be the sequence generated by Gradient Descent algorithm with **the same** initial point $\tilde{x}^0=x^0$ and step-size $0<\alpha<2/\tilde{L}$ where $\tilde{L}$ is the Lipschitz constant of $\nabla \tilde{f}$:
\begin{equation}
\tilde{x}^{k+1}=\tilde{x}^k-\alpha\nabla \tilde{f} (\tilde{x}^k).
\end{equation}

**Can we prove that $\mathrm{dist}\left(\{\tilde{x}^k\}_k,\{{x}^k\}_k\right)$ is uniformly bounded, for any $A$ and step-size $0<\alpha<2/\tilde{L}$?**

I tried to prove it by assuming existence of a compact sublevel set $\mathcal{L}=\{x:f(x)\leq f(x^0)\}$ and using the fact that Gradient Descent generates a decreasing sequence of objective values (implying that the sequence remains in the compact sublevel set). However I cannot prove existence of a set independent of both $A$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: You can't, because $\tilde f$ may have Lipschitz constant $\gg L$ if $A$ is very large.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for the response. I meant to reduce the step-size to maintain convergence. I don't have problem making the step-size arbitrarily small, but I am interested to know what happens to the sequence of DGD when such convex quadratic term is added. I modify the post to clarify.